# How to assign different css translation value per class?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

```css
.buttons > * {
  transition: transform 700ms;
} 
.buttons > .one.closed {
  transform: translateY(-10vh);
}
.buttons > .two.closed {
  transform: translateY(-20vh);
}
.buttons > .three.closed {
  transform: translateY(-30vh);
}
```

I have this code, on click i add .closed class to the three elements, is there a way to achieve the same effect without writing the css rule n times? I'm fine with doing it through js

This for example doesn't work :

```js
  const menuElements = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons > :not(.main)");
  menuElements.forEach((el, key) => {
    el.setAttribute("transform", -10 * key + "vh");
    el.classList.toggle("closed");
  });
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1cofL06p/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to insert translateY to the setAttribute. Anyhow, I think this should work:

```js
function fn() {
  const menuElements = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons > div:not(.main)");
  menuElements.forEach((el, key) => {
    el.style.transform = `translateY(${-20 * key}vh)`;
    el.classList.toggle("closed");
  });
}
```

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 69vh;
}


.buttons > * {
  transition: transform 700ms;
}
```

```html
   <div onclick="fn()" class="buttons">
      <div class="main" style="content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png');"></div>
      <div class="stats" style="content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png');"></div>
      <div
        class="settings"
        style="content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png');"
      ></div>
      <div class="close" style="content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png');"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work, I've posted a fiddle showing your code. You can see it works when I have the css rule defined, when I comment it out and try to set it manually like your example with javascript, nothing happens.

Comment: I see my mistake :) Thanks